# Getting the PID of a scenic component/scene

Tags: elixir, pid, gen-server

Quick question, in the Scenic docs it suggests that you can interact with any scene as you would any GenServer:

> You are free to send your own messages to scenes just as you would
> with any other GenServer process. You can use the handle_info/2 ,
> handle_cast/2 and handle_call/3 callbacks as you would normally.

I understand how this would work, but I’m unsure of how to actually get the PID of the scene to send messages to.

Using observer theres a table called `_scenic_scenes_table_`, but i’m guessing that’s not a public API.

I hope I’m not missing anything too obvious.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Kernel.send/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#send/2) accepts the destination of type [`Process.dest()`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#t:dest/0) which can be `pid()`, `port()`, *or* `registered_name`.

As scenes are [registered](https://hexdocs.pm/scenic/getting_started.html#configure-scenic) this would most likely work:

```rb
send(MyApp.Scene.Example, {:my, :info, :message})
```